# best way to handler trigger Recursive call

Tags: apex, triggercontext, recursion, trigger

Below is my code snippet that I have used. And also I used static Boolean to handle the recursive call.

But when I update more than 200 records then trigger only process first 200 record not all the records after 200.

So I think this is not a best solution to use static Boolean variable.

So what will be the best solution for this ?

```
trigger RN_Account on Account (after update) 
{
    RN_AccountHandler handler = new RN_AccountHandler();
    if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate && RN_AccountHandler.isUpdate)
    {
        RN_AccountHandler.isUpdate = false;
        handler.onAfterUpdate(Trigger.newMap, Trigger.OldMap);
    }
}
```

Handler

```
public with sharing class RN_AccountHandler 
{
    public static Boolean isUpdate = true;
    public void onAfterUpdate(map<Id, Account> mapNewAccount, map<Id, Account> mapOldAccount)
    {
        system.debug('========mapNewAccount.values()============'+mapNewAccount.values().size());
    }
}
```

I have added `RN_AccountHandler.isUpdate` to handle the

[image]

Comment: Are you firing this trigger by running some code in anonymous window?

Comment: @javanoob yes I am testing from anonymous window..

Comment: Use a static map of IDs

Comment: If your anonymous code is sending 400 records for update, trigger process first 200 and assigns the flag value to false and the next set of 200 records are skipped. There was an excellent post by @KeithC where he explained this problem clearly. If I find link, I will post here.

Comment: @javanoob yeah sure..

Comment: @cropredy you want to say store all the ids in map. If Id store in map then don't call the handler method else call the handler method?

Comment: @cropredy, sorry for confusing you with KeithC in my previous post. here is the link http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/110636/dml-limits-are-reset-when/110658#110658

Comment: (1) - No -- save IDs in map, call handler as normal but if ID in handler exists in map, do nothing in handler. You are, in effect, creating `n` recursion control flags, where `n` is the number of IDs processed on some previous handler invocation. When handler is invoked on iteraton `j`, some of the ids may not have been previously processed as you don't know what else may be going in the chain of previous triggers/workflows/services

Comment: @cropredy I have added [one answer](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/115933/18731). I used set of id as static variable. Can you please take a look and let me know your thoughts.

Comment: @sfdcweb I think, as code run in anonymous window runs in a single transaction context, that's why after executing first 200 records when the trigger starts executing the next chunk it finds the static variable not set to false.

Comment: You may not face the problem in realtime execution i.e. when you try to load same 600 records using data loader or import wizard.

Comment: @SaumyaRanjanSatapathy yes you are correct.. This usecase only come when we execute code from dev console or if we update more than 200 record from apex code..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So as [@cropredy](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/2602/cropredy) suggested using static map instead this is what I tried. I used static set to solve this issue.

I can't say this is the best solution or not but this is working.

may me some usecases will be there please feel free to comment on this post.

So I used set of Id static variable.

### Trigger

```
trigger RN_Account on Account (after update) 
{
   RN_AccountHandler handler = new RN_AccountHandler();

   if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate && !RN_AccountHandler.setAccountIds.containsAll(Trigger.newMap.KeySet())) 
   { 
      RN_AccountHandler.setAccountIds.addAll(Trigger.newMap.KeySet());
      handler.onAfterUpdate(Trigger.newMap, Trigger.OldMap);
    }
}
```

### Handler

```
public with sharing class RN_AccountHandler 
{   
    public static set<Id> setAccountIds = new set<Id>();

    public void onAfterUpdate(map<Id, Account> mapNewAccount, map<Id, Account> mapOldAccount)
    {
       system.debug('====11========='+mapNewAccount.values().size());
       update [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id IN: mapNewAccount.keyset()];
    }
}
```

### One more solution

IN controller after execution just make the boolean to true

### Trigger

```
trigger RN_Account on Account (after update) 
{
    RN_AccountHandler handler = new RN_AccountHandler();
    if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate && RN_AccountHandler.isUpdate)
    {
        RN_AccountHandler.isUpdate = false;
        handler.onAfterUpdate(Trigger.newMap, Trigger.OldMap);
    }
}
```

### Controller

```
public with sharing class RN_AccountHandler 
{
    public static Boolean isUpdate = true;
    public void onAfterUpdate(map<Id, Account> mapNewAccount, map<Id, Account> mapOldAccount)
    {
        system.debug('============'+mapNewAccount.values().size());
        update [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id IN: mapNewAccount.keyset()];
        RN_AccountHandler.isUpdate = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: We would need this workaround only when trying to update more than 200 records from anonymous window right? For other situations, your original code from the post should work fine.

Comment: @javanoob exactly.. my above will work for less than 200 records with recursive and this above will work for more than 200 records with recursive  situation.

Comment: @sfdcweb, my only doubt is if the collection of records in the first recursion call is always the same as in the first batch.
Let's say SF executes after trigger for the first 200 batch, it triggers another execution of the trigger with the same set of records, right?

Comment: I'm not sure about order of execution of triggers when records updated in batches. Recursive calls are fired when all records are updated or when first batch is updated?

Comment: @Edelrabe let say if you are updating 400 records at a time then first 1-200 records will be execute then after 201-400 records will be execute.. recursive call can be fired from any time if you are updating single or first/second batch records updated in trigger handler or via workflow.. so in that case trigger should not fire again... so above my approach should work on this case,...

Comment: sfdcweb -- (1) I don't follow the 'one more solution'; (2) I think I would let the handler decide whether to reprocess rather than the trigger.  (3) things get more complicated if you allow for partial successes in the DML. see http://cropredysfdc.com/2015/04/26/245/ for a discussion - you would need to actually clear the static set of ids for the partial success records as they will be replayed by SFDC.  (4) Of course, your best alternative might be to reengineer whatever does the >200 DML operation and break into multiple transactions

Answer (score 1):

The only approach I know is to store a Set of Ids that have been processed already as @cropredy suggested. So the code will be something like this:

```
trigger RN_Account on Account (after update) 
{
    RN_AccountHandler handler = new RN_AccountHandler();
    if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate)
    {
        RN_AccountHandler.isUpdate = false;
        handler.onAfterUpdate(Trigger.newMap, Trigger.OldMap);
    }
}

public with sharing class RN_AccountHandler 
{
    public static Set<Id> processedIDs = new Set<Id>();
    public void onAfterUpdate(map<Id, Account> mapNewAccount, map<Id, Account> mapOldAccount)
    {
        system.debug('========mapNewAccount.values()============'+mapNewAccount.values().size());
        for (Id accountId : mapNewAccount.keySet()) {
            if (!processedIDs.contains(accountId)) {
                // your code
                processedIDs.add(accountId);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes exactly... This is the way i found yesterday... hope someone have better idea than this. else I will accept this ans..

Comment: Yesterday I was thinking to use static `set<Id>` and use addAll method to add all the values and check containsAll to check each batch ids exist or not. this can be a way but I think if only one record updates instead chunk records then it will may not work..

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you've put your public static boolean in your class instead of in your trigger. Your class is called from the trigger and needs to be called for every 200 records when the trigger is called the FIRST time. By putting the Boolean in your class, your preventing the class from running more than once per trigger invocation. Relocate your boolean as follows using an external trigger helper class to hold the boolean.

```
trigger RN_Account on Account (after update) 
{
   if(!triggerHelper.FirstRun){
      FirstRun = true; 
      RN_AccountHandler handler = new RN_AccountHandler();
      if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate)
      {
          handler.onAfterUpdate(Trigger.newMap, Trigger.OldMap);
      }
    }
}


public with sharing triggerHelper class {

   public static boolean FirstRun = false;

}
```

When the trigger runs the SECOND time, the boolean will be true, causing the trigger to immediately exit.

Comment: crmprogdev.. nop it is still not processing more than 200 records(next chunk records).

Comment: Did you catch the last edit and remove the handler class boolean from your handler class as well as the handler class boolean from your trigger?

Comment: Yes now I removed `RN_AccountHandler.isUpdate = false;` from trigger but it is processing only first 200 records.. let me updated question I also tried with removing `RN_AccountHandler.isUpdate` boolean from trigger if condition.. still the same.

Comment: Okay, you removed the && RN_AccountHandler.isUpdate? Try removing the with sharing from the trigger helper class. Are you certain you have more than 200 records? Does system debug confirm that? Ahh, wait a min, I see an error, it should be `if(!triggerHelper.FirstRun)`. Oh, you had caught that. Wouldn't have compiled.

Comment: crmprogdev.. Yes I removed `RN_AccountHandler.isUpdate` and testing I have updated the same in my question. Pls check.. let me know If I am doing anything wrong.. Also added screenshot. how I am testing and in my org 999 records present..

Comment: So, you're running that query to fire to the trigger? What does your debug log show? Add debug statements to your trigger code. You can't test a trigger all by itself from execute anonymous. You need to do something to the data for the trigger to fire. Create a test class to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
public class RN_AccountHandler
{
    public static boolean isExecuting = false;

    public static void onAfterUpdate(map<Id, Account> mapNewAccount, map<Id, Account> mapOldAccount)
    {
        if( RN_AccountHandler.isExecuting )
        {
            // avoid recursion: if was executed during the same context 
            return;
        }

        RN_AccountHandler.isExecuting = true;

        // your code for after update logic
    }
}
```

Comment: Oleksiy... have you tested this ans.. It looks same like above mine.. you are just added `isExecuting ` inside method..