# How to resolve 'maximum trigger depth exceeded' error in my trigger?

Tags: apex, trigger

My problem statement is as follows:

1) I have a custom object where due to business requirements I had to add two new fields named **'CSO Work Duration' and 'DA Work Duration'**. These fields are calculating the Work duration of a case in the status CSO/DA. This is done via trigger. These fields are critical for the reporting purpose.

2) Now we need values in these fields for the records which are already in production. There are more than 3000+ records as of now. To update these records I thought of creating the trigger which will run only once and calculate these field values and update them in production.

3) Now the issue I am facing in my trigger is that I am receiving the **'maximum trigger depth exceeded'** error.

Below is the code for the same:

**Note : Updated trigger to fire on Before event.**

**Trigger**

```
Trigger CaseRecordUpdateTrigger on Case_Status_History__c(Before Update) 
{
    IF(Trigger.isBefore)
    {
        IF(Trigger.isUpdate)
        {
            List<Case_Status_History__c> CSHToBeProcessed1 = New List<Case_Status_History__c>();
            boolean callThatMethod1 = false;
            For(Case_Status_History__c CSH : Trigger.New)
            {
                IF((CSH.New_Status_Value__c == 'Closed') && ((CSH.CSO_Work_Duration__c == 0.00) || (CSH.DA_Work_Duration__c == 0.00)))
                {
                    CSHToBeProcessed1.Add(CSH);
                    callThatMethod1 = true;
                }                               
             }
           if(callThatMethod1) 
           {
               CaseRecordUpdateTriggerHelper.UpdateWorkDurationField(CSHToBeProcessed1);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

**Trigger Helper Class**

```
Public Class CaseRecordUpdateTriggerHelper
{
    Public Static Void UpdateWorkDurationField(List<Case_Status_History__c> CSHIds)
    {
    Set<Id> CaseVal = New Set<Id>();
    List<Case_Status_History__c> CSHToUpdate = New List<Case_Status_History__c>();

    For(Case_Status_History__c C : CSHIds)
    {
        CaseVal.add(C.Parent_Case__c);
    }

    List<Case_Status_History__c> CSHList1 = [Select Id,Name,Parent_Case__c,Status_Value__c,New_Status_Value__c,CSO_Name__c,DA_Name__c,Time_Elapsed__c,CSO_Work_Duration__c,DA_Work_Duration__c,CreatedDate,CreatedById FROM Case_Status_History__c WHERE Isdeleted= False AND New_Status_Value__c = 'Closed' AND Parent_case__c =: CaseVal ORDER BY Name ASC];
    List<Case_Status_History__c> CSHList2 = [Select Id,Name,Parent_Case__c,Status_Value__c,New_Status_Value__c,CSO_Name__c,DA_Name__c,Time_Elapsed__c,CSO_Work_Duration__c,DA_Work_Duration__c,CreatedDate,CreatedById FROM Case_Status_History__c WHERE Isdeleted= False AND Status_Value__c =: ('CSO Working , DA Working') AND Parent_case__c =: CaseVal ORDER BY Name ASC];

    For(Case_Status_History__c CSH1 : CSHList1)
    {
        Decimal Sum1 = 0;
        Decimal Sum2 = 0;

        Case_Status_History__c CSHU = New Case_Status_History__c();
        CSHU.Id = CSH1.Id;

        For(Case_Status_History__c CSH2 : CSHList2)
        {
            IF(CSH1.Parent_Case__c == CSH2.Parent_Case__c)
            {
                IF(CSH2.Status_Value__c == 'CSO Working')
                {
                    System.debug('---1---');
                    Sum1 = Sum1 + CSH2.Time_Elapsed__c;
                    System.debug('---Sum1---'+Sum1);
                }

                IF(CSH2.Status_Value__c == 'DA Working')
                {
                    System.debug('---2---');
                    Sum2 = Sum2 + CSH2.Time_Elapsed__c;
                    System.debug('---Sum2---'+Sum2);
                }
            }
        }

        CSHU.CSO_Work_Duration__c = Sum1;
        CSHU.DA_Work_Duration__c = Sum2;
        CSHToUpdate.Add(CSHU);
    }
    Update CSHToUpdate;
    }
}
```

Below is the Snapshot of what I need.

[image]

Please help me in resolving the error.

Thanks!

Comment: This occur when you perform DML on trigger record this cause multiple fire the trigger....  In this case go with before update event for updating records value.. OR add a recursion handler like http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/115767/best-way-to-handler-trigger-recursive-call

Comment: @sfdcweb : If I change it to before trigger then recursion is not happening. But the update which I want on field is still not happening. Can you help me in knowing where I am going wrong ? I have updated the code in my question. Thanks!

Comment: Ruchi.. since you are updating trigger context field value and all the related child records associated to parent case record then you need to go with after context... And in after context just use a boolean value for handing the recursive call

Comment: @sfdcweb  : Using Boolean also given me recursive error. Is there any other place where I am going wrong ? :(  I have again edited my code in question.

Comment: Ruchi... can you please update you question with latest code and let me review your code

Comment: @sfdcweb :  I have added latest code there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you need Just take a Boolean variable handler recursive call

```
public Class CaseRecordUpdateTriggerHelper
{
   public static Boolean isUpdate = true;//take this variable
   public Static Void UpdateWorkDurationField(List<Case_Status_History__c> CSHIds)
   {
      //rest of your code
      // update DML i.e. Update CSHToUpdate
      CaseRecordUpdateTriggerHelper.isUpdate = true;
   }
}
```

And in your trigger

```
Trigger CaseRecordUpdateTrigger on Case_Status_History__c(Before Update) 
{
    IF(Trigger.isBefore)
    {
        IF(Trigger.isUpdate && CaseRecordUpdateTriggerHelper.isUpdate)
        {
            //rest code
            if(CaseRecordUpdateTriggerHelper.isUpdate) 
           {
               CaseRecordUpdateTriggerHelper.isUpdate = false;
              CaseRecordUpdateTriggerHelper.UpdateWorkDurationField(CSHToBeProcessed1);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your welcome @Ruchi.